# Vertical interchangable system using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I am currently working with my local youth council to try and recreate their site.
http://cardiffyouthcouncil.wixsite.com/tools4life

I'm currently going through and re-coding it(Basically making a new one that looks like it) I am struggling to find something I could use to switch out content.

I know I could just create separate pages for each but I want to avoid that. I was planning on all content being interchangeable without reloading the site, only for the large categories would I do that.

All scripts I could find online either have them like tabs next to one another(I want them to stack on top like the current site) and/or have an annoying border around them. I don't know a lot of Javascript so Is what I'm asking possible and does anyone have any examples/know where to find code? (Sorry if this is to open ended)

Answer (score 0):

You should look for 'single page application'.

There are many ways to do this, like Angular or just AJAX.

Here are some links:

https://anandnalya.com/2012/03/building-a-single-page-webapp-with-jquery/
https://ilovecoding.org/lessons/ajax-create-a-single-page-app-with-jquery